# Nested controller issue in Java FX

Tags: java, javafx, controller, javafx-2

I'm trying to include controller(`SelectedIssueController`) in my main layout (*main.fxml*). But I get the following error:

```
Can not set lt.mypackage.controllers.SelectedIssueController field lt.mypackage.controllers.MainController.selectedIssueController to javafx.scene.layout.VBox
```

Line in main.fxml:

```xml
  <fx:include fx:id="selectedIssueController" source="controllers/selectedissue.fxml" />
```

My selectedissue.fxml:

```xml
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="lt.mypackage.controllers.SelectedIssueController" fillWidth="false" SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
    <children>
     .....
     .....
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Line in `MainController`:

```
@FXML
private SelectedIssueController selectedIssueController;
```

As I understand it injects `VBox` object now, but I need `SelectedIssueController`. What is wrong with my current implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `FXMLLoader` appends `Controller` to the `fx:id` specified in the `fx:include` element to get the name of the field to inject the controller to. Therefore it should be either:

```
@FXML
private SelectedIssueController selectedIssueControllerController;
```

or

```xml
<fx:include fx:id="selectedIssue" source="controllers/selectedissue.fxml" />
```

The value injected to the field without the `Controller` suffix is the value created for the `fx:include`, i.e. the `Object` created for the root of the included fxml.